# Trix editor isn't working in Heroku, but working fine on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, trix

I've used trix editor before, but this time it isn't working as planned when deployed to heroku. The editor doesn't show up, and the input is reduced to a tiny square, not clickable.

Here is the expected behavior on localhost:
[Trix editor showing up and working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ipc.png)
But, on heroku, it shows like this:
[Trix editor not showing and not clickable as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACBu7.png)

On my rails Gemfile:

```
gem 'trix-rails', require: 'trix'
```

On application.scss:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= stub scaffolds
 */
 @import "trix";
 @import "font-awesome";
```

And on application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require trix
```

I have the following code on my _form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field" id="blog-editor">
  <%= form.label :content %>
  <%= form.trix_editor :content, id: :backoffice_blog_content %>
</div>
```

I can't find where the problem is. I've tried precompiling the assets so far, but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: You [shouldn't use sprockets directives in a sass file](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note)

Comment: I solved the problem! Yes, there was some errors, jquery wasn't working because of an import order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console log present a series of errors about Jquery. It wasn't working properly because of an import order (I was using require tree and, in the alphabetical order, a file required another that was compiled after it). Basically, you shouldn't mix sprockets directives, sass and other forms of import in the same project. (it wasn't my fault, it's a legacy project)

But that's it, that resolved the problem.